# Can pytesseract read and print exponents?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

Using this code

```py
    '''
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\New folder\tesseract.exe'
    # Grayscale image
    img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\gusta\Downloads\PyQuad-master\test.png").convert('L')  
    ret,img = cv2.threshold(np.array(img), 180, 500, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    # Older versions of pytesseract need a pillow image
    # Convert back if needed
    img = Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8))
    
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    with open('file.txt', mode ='w') as f:
        f.write(text)
    '''
```

I get a text file:

```
Find the y-intercept of the parabola with the followin

y = —6x? — 10x — 2
```

Which was converted from:

[image: This Image]

Is there a way I could get it to read the ^2 exponent and also print it as ^2?

Comment: The term for the formatting of those characters is superscript. I don’t think Tesseract knows anything about number values when it reads digits, or exponents - it just turns black pixels on white background into characters as well as it can. Seaching for tesseract superscript finds things like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531650/recognizing-superscript-characters-using-ocr#9724882 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/v-Sf6Uwqx5I. So spending a little time searching might be productive for you.

Comment: Since all of the data I am working with have an exponent of 2, I added some code to just replace '?' with ^2. But my follow up question is: The 'x' is sometimes read as '2', and how can I fix that?